# Are Cartesian coordinates unable to explore multi-valued functions beyond the principle value?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

By expressing the domain of a function in polar coordinates it is possible to take the function beyond it’s [principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value) (ie beyond 2$\pi$) to reveal the full beauty & complexity of it’s [Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface). Am I right in saying that Cartesian co-ordinates are inherently limited in this regard in a similar way that real numbers hide the greater truths revealed by using complex numbers?

Comment: How would you use polar coordinates to reveal the full beauty and complexity of, say, $(z^2 - 1)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Rahul: By taking the argument beyond 2\pi. Am I right in thinking that Cartesian coordinates cannot do this?

Comment: OK, let $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta>2\pi$, so we have $f(z) = (re^{2i\theta}-1)^{1/2}$. Now what?

Comment: @Raul. If I may take a simpler function: F(z)=z^0.5 then as we go beyond 2PI we see the second sheet of its Riemann surface (see link below). I don't think this can be done with Cartesian co-ordinates (unless you tell me otherwise). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface